# Autodesk Webhook API event dm.folder.deleted doesn't seem to work

Tags: autodesk-webhooks

I have made several tests with Autodesk's Webhook API and I cannot figure out what the `dm.folder.deleted` event does (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/data_management_events/dm.folder.deleted/).

I have registered the Webhook with the POST request as documented on a sample directory in Autodesk Construction Cloud:

```
curl -X 'POST'\
     -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/webhooks/v1/systems/data/events/dm.folder.deleted/hooks'\
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json'\
     -H 'authorization: Bearer bNU4P0trbQKNSzxWksLPTzSbbmUz'\
     -d '{
            "callbackUrl": "http://bf067e05.ngrok.io/callback",
            "scope": {
                "folder": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.s424tpjyS_yYBs5ozch94g"
            },
            "hookAttribute": {
                "something": 34
            }
        }'
```

In my eyes there are two possible triggers for that Webhook:

- When a folder is deleted inside the folder with the registered hook.
- When the folder itself is deleted.

Both cases won't trigger my callback URL.

Just to be sure that I have not made any setup mistakes: I have also registered the `dm.folder.modified` event and this one triggers if I create/rename/delete a folder inside the target folder.

I have also fetched all the registered webhooks and can see that the `dm.folder.deleted` was correctly applied to the desired folder.

Is there another action required which triggers `dm.folder.deleted` or is it just not working?